# ¿Cómo ajustar valores de una lista de listas según cierta tolerancia?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente lista de listas:

```
original =  [[873, 3270, 873, 284],
             [1641, 3271, 1641, 283],
             [877, 3271, 877, 283],
             [1637, 3270, 1637, 284],
             [142, 244, 2373, 244],
             [143, 3267, 848, 3267],
             [905, 1707, 1610, 1707],
             [904, 1710, 1611, 1710],
             [1665, 1830, 2373, 1830],
             [1666, 2487, 2372, 2487],
             [1666, 1467, 2372, 1467],
             [1666, 2847, 2372, 2847],
             [1665, 1470, 2373, 1470],
             [1666, 1827, 2372, 1827],
             [1665, 2850, 2373, 2850],
             [1665, 2490, 2373, 2490]]
```

Para darle un contexto a estos datos, digamos que cada elemento de `original` es una lista de coordenadas en la forma `[x1,y1,x2,y2]`, estas coordenadas representan segmentos. La idea es "simplificar" o "ajustar" los puntos de acuerdo a un nivel configurable. Si ven los valores que corresponden a `x1` verán fácilmente valores bastante similares en algunos casos, en las otras columnas también se dan estos casos. La idea es sencilla, si hay una coordenada con el valor `1665` y otras con el valor `1666`, lo que se busca es aproximar ambos a un único valor, digamos al primero que aparezca. La tolerancia debería ser ajustable, por ejemplo 5, de forma tal que si primero aparece el valor 1665 y luego el 1660, este último sea ajustado y pase a ser 1665 (hay una distancia de 5 unidades entre ambos puntos que cumple con la tolerancia definida). La idea subyacente es simplificar los puntos de origen y destino de las rectas que son cercanas en dichos puntos.

En el ejemplo dado, la solución debiera ser algo como esta lista:

```
[[873, 3270, 873, 284],
 [1641, 3270, 1641, 284],
 [873, 3270, 873, 284],
 [1641, 3270, 1641, 284],
 [142, 244, 2373, 244],
 [142, 3270, 848, 3270],
 [905, 1707, 1610, 1707],
 [905, 1707, 1610, 1707],
 [1665, 1830, 2373, 1830],
 [1665, 2487, 2373, 2487],
 [1665, 1467, 2373, 1467],
 [1665, 2847, 2373, 2847],
 [1665, 1467, 2373, 1467],
 [1665, 1830, 2373, 1830],
 [1665, 2847, 2373, 2847],
 [1665, 2487, 2373, 2487]]
```

Una aclaración, esto es un problema real, que me parece interesante, ya le encontré una forma de resolverlo, la cual no me convence del todo y por supuesto aceptaré cualquier otra solución más óptima o más simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurrió es esto:

```
import pprint    

def simplificar(mylista, level):

    aprox = {0:{}, 1:{}}

    for i in (0,1):
      valor = list(sum(list(zip(*[(e[0+i], e[2+i]) for e in mylista])), ()))
      for e in valor:
        if e not in aprox[i]:
          aprox[i].update({e-x: e for x in range(-level, level + 1, 1)})

    for i,e in enumerate(mylista):

      mylista[i][0] = aprox[0][e[0]]
      mylista[i][1] = aprox[1][e[1]]
      mylista[i][2] = aprox[0][e[2]]
      mylista[i][3] = aprox[1][e[3]]

    return(mylista)

pprint.pprint(simplificar(original, 5))
```

- Con los valores de `x` (es decir `x1` y `x2`) armo una lista (hacemos lo mismo con los de `y`)
- En esta lista voy armando un diccionario con los valores a ajustar, es decir si el valor es 567 y el nivel de ajuste es 2, armaría los siguientes elementos del diccionario `{565:567, 566:567, 567:567, 568:567, 569:567}`
- Con los siguientes valores, si no se encuentran en este diccionario repito el proceso anterior, pero si nos encontramos con el valor `569`, entonces reemplazaríamos el valor original de la lista por el valor del diccionario es de `567`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesante pregunta. He estado pensando si podría resolverse usando `numpy` y he encontrado un posible enfoque que hace algo diferente a lo que pides, pero de resultados similares por término medio.

Se trata de usar `numpy.digitize()` para aproximar todos los datos de las columnas de tu array a una serie de "valores prefijados".

Aunque podríamos construir esos valores prefijados de forma más o menos inteligente, esto implicaría usar técnicas de *clustering*, demasiado complejo quizás y ante lo que puede ser preferible tu enfoque.

Sin embargo podemos ir a una solución más simple y es que esos valores prefijados sean todos los múltiplos de una cierta cantidad dada. Por ejemplo 3. De este modo valores como 565, 566 y 567 se sustituirían todos por 567. Ahora bien, 568 y 569 ya serían cambiados a 570. En ese sentido no sale lo mismo que en tu algoritmo, pero puede ser una aproximación razonable.

Este es el código, que gracias a las operaciones vectorizadas de numpy, queda muy breve:

```
import numpy as np
def simplificar(original, level):
  original = np.array(original)
  result = []
  for col in original.T:
    levels = np.arange(0, max(col)+level, level)
    result.append(np.take(levels, np.digitize(col, levels, right=True)))
  return np.array(result).T
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
original = [
       [ 873, 3270,  873,  284],
       [1641, 3271, 1641,  283],
       [ 877, 3271,  877,  283],
       [1637, 3270, 1637,  284],
       [ 142,  244, 2373,  244],
       [ 143, 3267,  848, 3267],
       [ 905, 1707, 1610, 1707],
       [ 904, 1710, 1611, 1710],
       [1665, 1830, 2373, 1830],
       [1666, 2487, 2372, 2487],
       [1666, 1467, 2372, 1467],
       [1666, 2847, 2372, 2847],
       [1665, 1470, 2373, 1470],
       [1666, 1827, 2372, 1827],
       [1665, 2850, 2373, 2850],
       [1665, 2490, 2373, 2490]]
simplificar(original, 3)
```

> Resultado:
>
> ```
> array([[ 873, 3270,  873,  285],
>        [1641, 3273, 1641,  285],
>        [ 879, 3273,  879,  285],
>        [1638, 3270, 1638,  285],
>        [ 144,  246, 2373,  246],
>        [ 144, 3267,  849, 3267],
>        [ 906, 1707, 1611, 1707],
>        [ 906, 1710, 1611, 1710],
>        [1665, 1830, 2373, 1830],
>        [1668, 2487, 2373, 2487],
>        [1668, 1467, 2373, 1467],
>        [1668, 2847, 2373, 2847],
>        [1665, 1470, 2373, 1470],
>        [1668, 1827, 2373, 1827],
>        [1665, 2850, 2373, 2850],
>        [1665, 2490, 2373, 2490]])
> ```

Como referencia, estos son los resultados de tu algoritmo para level=2:

> ```
> array([[ 873, 3270,  873,  284],
>        [1641, 3270, 1641,  284],
>        [ 877, 3270,  877,  284],
>        [1637, 3270, 1637,  284],
>        [ 142,  244, 2373,  244],
>        [ 142, 3267,  848, 3267],
>        [ 905, 1707, 1610, 1707],
>        [ 905, 1710, 1610, 1710],
>        [1665, 1830, 2373, 1830],
>        [1665, 2487, 2373, 2487],
>        [1665, 1467, 2373, 1467],
>        [1665, 2847, 2373, 2847],
>        [1665, 1470, 2373, 1470],
>        [1665, 1827, 2373, 1827],
>        [1665, 2850, 2373, 2850],
>        [1665, 2490, 2373, 2490]])
> ```

Si comparamos estos resultados con los que produce tu algoritmo (para level=2), la diferencia entre los valores es de 2 como máximo (es 0 en la mayoría de los casos, de 1 en 11 casos y 2 en 6 casos).

La diferencia en tiempo de ejecución, sorprendentemente (al menos para mi), no es significativa. Tu código es muy rápido porque usa estructuras nativas de python (listas y diccionarios). El código de `numpy` es muy rápido porque está vectorizado e implementado en C, pero se pierde tiempo en las conversiones entre listas python y matrices numpy y viceversa. Al final vienen a tardar lo mismo ambos enfoques.

Comment: Una interesante aproximación al problema, me gusta la idea de usar `numpy` ya que los datos vienen efectivamente de una array de este tipo. No conocía `digitize()` , buen aporte. +1.